# Angular 4 get parent, child and next element from html

Tags: angular

I am trying to create a button which when pressed returns the parents parents next element. I'm using

```
<button (click)="onClick(this)">show more</button>
```

in the html file and in the .ts file i got

```
onClick(obj) {
    alert(obj.parent().parent().next());
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? I am unclear about your question

Comment: When the button is clicked, I want to collapse or expand the div below the button. I have a list of elements so i need to limit this to the one below the current button clicked. So i thought the best way to get this done was to collapse and expand the div which is the next of the parent of the parent of the button.

Comment: Ohh that make sense, have you considered doing it with jQuery in your angular 4 codes? If you know the element like $(#yourElement).parent()?

Comment: We are generating a list of elements from a database, so i got multiple buttons with the same class and id. thats why i am trying to pass the button to the onClick function

Answer (score 6):

You can pass `$event` parameter in your click function and then use `$event` to get child element i.e. target

```
<button (click)="onClick($event)">show more</button>
```

in the HTML file

```
onClick(e) {
    console.log("Child:", e.target);
    console.log("Parent:", e.target.parentNode); 
    console.log("Parents parent sibling:", e.target.parentNode.parentNode.nextSibling);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

First create a reference to your button element

```
<button (click)="onClick()" #btn>show more</button>
```

.ts file

```
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@ViewChild('btn') public btn: HTMLButtonElement;

onClick() {
    console.log(this.btn['nativeElement'].parentElement.parentElement.nextSibling);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution, if you need it a bit more dynamically, you can try this.
This will allow you to change the HTML code without manually deleting the parent depth each time.

The calling function to change a class in the closest li Tag by clickevent on a HTML-Element deep inside the li

```
setClassOnParent(e, yourClassName){
const parent = this.getParentElByNodeName(e.originalEvent.target, 'li');
parent.classList.add(yourClassName);
}
```

The function which return the first closest parent by given nodeName

```
getParentElByNodeName(target, nodeName) {
    let actualNode = target.parentElement;
    while (actualNode.nodeName !== nodeName.toUpperCase()) {
        actualNode = actualNode.parentElement;
    }
    return actualNode;
}
```

If you want, you can extend the function with an enclosing element, to where the parents should be searched. "ul" as Example